# Extjs6 apply property from config via function

Tags: javascript, extjs, store, extjs6

I used to write this in extjs4:

```
Ext.define('Superstore', {
    extends: 'Ext.data.Store'

    config : {
        customer : null,
    },

    applyCustomer : function (value) {
        this.customer = value;
    },

    model : 'Supermodel'

});
```

I tried the same in extjs6, but with no success:´

```
Ext.define('Supermodel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: ['Ext.data.reader.Json', 'Ext.data.proxy.Rest'],

    config: {
        customer: null
    },

    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'string'},
        ...
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: '/customers/{customer}/users',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }

    },

    applyCustomer: function (value) {
        this.customer = value;
        this.proxy.url.replace('{customer}', value);
    }

});
```

Did they remove the magic?
Or is there any other, better, way to build my url like in my code?
I've already seen a few solutions, but none of them fitted to my application.
I get the customerId via session which is sent by the backend after login. I would get the store via StoreManager, get the customer record and apply it to the proxy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to manipulate the value use the `update` function instead:

```
updateCustomer: function(newValue){
    this.proxy.url.replace('{customer}', newValue);
}
```

(And remove the `applyCustomer` function)

Comment: Is this function executed automatically?

Comment: It's not working. The function is not executed. The url is still customers/%7Bcustomer%7D/users
(it should be at least _/customers/null/users_)

Comment: `updateCustomer` is never called when `applyCustomer` returns null or undefined. That's one of the benefits of using `updateCustomer()`. And yes, `applyCustomer` is an autogenerated method which should return a value. So what you are doing in ExtJs 4 is also wrong.
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?171113-Difference-between-update-and-apply-magic-methods